# Automatic conversion to user define type in Python

Tags: python, class, python-3.4, arithmetic-expressions

I'm building a type ([dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number)) and can't find the way to make them behave nicely in arithmetic expressions, like the complex numbers in Python do:

```
>>> 2 + 3 + 7j
>>> 5 + 7j
```

In my case:

```
>>> 3 + 4 + 5e
>>> obvious type error
```

I can easily make it work in, manipulate __add__method,  the other way: my type + built in. I, also, can do it making external function add and passing parameters, but, obviously, nice integration with '+' is much better.
Thanks in advance.
PS Where to find Python modules source code (I could look in a complex class myself)?

Comment: Check [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__)

Comment: @niemmi: this looks good, will check it.

Comment: @niemmi: this is cool, just check, works for addition, with a some tricks for unsymmetrical opers too!

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic type conversion to user defined types in Python.

You need to implement the methods `_add__` and `__radd__`, `__sub__` and `__rsub__`, etc. to emulate the behaviour of numeric types.

See [the Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for a list of magic methods you need to implement.

You can find the source code of CPython at https://hg.python.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure You can do this. Those are called built-in types, and You can't expand them. However, You can do something like this:

```
class ENumber():
     def __init__(self, a=0, b=0):
         self.a = a
         self.b = b

     def __repr__(self):
         return "{} + {}e".format(self.a, self.b)

     def __add__(self, other):
         if isinstance(other, ENumber):
             return ENumber(self.a + other.a, self.b + other.b)
```

In action:

```
In [15]: x = ENumber(1, 1)

In [16]: y = ENumber(2, 2)

In [17]: x+y
Out[17]: 3 + 3e
```

Of course, You'll have to implement all other significant functions too.